# Storing application permissions in a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, permissions, store

I'm developing an application for our company that eventually will have lots of ways of restricting users to particular sections/modules. While the application is still small, I'd like to move to a new method of storing permissions that, as the application grows, will remain easy to maintain and query.

Currently in our MySQL database we have a table called "user" which stores the user's ID, username and password. In a separate table called "user_acl" is the following:

```
user_acl_id
acl_root
acl_news_read
acl_news_write
acl_news_modify
acl_reports_read
acl_reports_write
acl_reports_modify
acl_users_read
acl_users_write
acl_users_modify
```

We only have 3 modules at the minute, but over time more will be created and permissions for each will need to be added.

Rather than create a column for each permission, is there any other way or storing this information?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would do it this way.

```
table name: permission
columns: id, permission_name
```

and then I can assign multiple permissions to the user using a many to many relationship table

```
table name: user_permission
columns: permission_id, user_id
```

This design will allow me to add as many permission as I want, and assign it to as many user as i want.

While the above design go with your requirement, I have my own method of implementing ACL in my application. I am posting it here.

My method of implementation of ACL goes like this:

1. User will be assigned a role (Admin, guest, staff, public)
2. A role will have one or many permissions assigned to them (user_write, user_modify, report_read) etc.
3. Permission for the User will be inherited from the role to which he/she is
4. User can be assigned with manual permission apart from the permission inherited from role.

To do this I have come up with the following database design.

```
role
I store the role name here 
+----------+
| Field    |
+----------+
| id       |
| role_name |
+----------+

permission:
I store the permission name and key here 
Permission name is for displaying to user.
Permission key is for determining the permission.
+----------------+
| Field          |
+----------------+
| id             |
| permission_name |
| permission_key  |
+----------------+

role_permission
I assign permission to role here 
+---------------+
| Field         |
+---------------+
| id            |
| role_id       |
| permission_id |
+---------------+

user_role
I assign role to the user here 
+---------------+
| Field         |
+---------------+
| id            |
| user_id       |
| role_id       |
+---------------+

user_permission
I store the manual permission I may allow for the user here 
+---------------+
| Field         |
+---------------+
| id            |
| user_id       |
| permission_id |
+---------------+
```

This gives me more control over the ACL. I can allow superadmins to assign permission by themselves, and so on. As I said this is just to give you the idea.

Comment: How to add extra info about role like admin public etc? for example admin has some thing extra to add like company name..and user doesn't have this field?

Comment: I would store information in the related entity, you can add extra columns to the table, if you want to add more information for a role then you can add extra column in role table, same goes for user table

Comment: if i have user table with fields username and password.which is generic for all users. and i have members table with some extra field like company name, address etc..also i have admin with some more info..so i need to use supertype/subtype relation for user with memebers admin?

Answer (score 0):

Like Ibrahim says, create a new table specifically for your permissions.  Assign a numerical value to a user which represents their permission level, say 1 = read, 2= write/read, 3 = modify/write/read.  Then in your code, check for proper permission level before allowing a user to perform a specific task.  If they don't have the required value (3 to modify or >=2 to write) then you block that ability.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have five tables:

```
user
user_x_profile
profile
profile_x_function
function
```

You set up various "generic" profiles "viewer", "employee", "manager" etc.

You set up a "function" entry for each object you want to control.

Then link the functions to the profiles in profile_x_function.

Then assign one or more profiles to each user.

This cuts the administration effort. Say you want to add another function that only "managers" can use -- you just add a new entry in the function table then add an entry in the "profile_x_function" table which links to the "manager" profile the permission to the manager profile and its available to all managers.

To query access you will need a five table join, but you are only selecting one permision attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In a very famous MySQL performance book *High Performance MySQL*, the author specifically mentioned ACL as *where data type like `SET` could be used.* They use following example to demonstrate such use cases:

```sql
CREATE TABLE acl (
    permissions SET('CAN_READ', 'CAN_WRITE', 'CAN_DELETE') NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO acl VALUES ('CAN_READ,CAN_WRITE');
SELECT permissions FROM acl WHERE find_in_set('CAN_READ', permissions);
```

The problem is that, mentioned in the book as well, you can't modify the permissions set easily (you have to use `ALTER TABLE`), neither can you declare a column typed `SET` as an index, which may causes performance issue.

You can also use something like `TINYINT` to "wrap" the ACL list, the cons is that it's harder to read as well as to code `SELECT` sentence.