# Advise with storing permissions in a database

Tags: mysql, permissions

Just looking for some advise on how I could store if a user has permissions to do a certain task.

The way the project is laid out is there are lots of "section" and then there are multiple permissions associated within that section.
For example

Management section permissions

- can delete
- can add
- can move

Creation section permissions

- can create
- can createbigger
- can createbest

Each user can have any of these permissions and does not require the previous permission in order to have it

Probably not the best example but I cant think of anything
I was thinking of having a system using intergers kinda like linux's permission system but was wondering what other people would recommend sorry if my question is not very clear.
Thanks!
Forgot to mention I indtend of storing the permissions in a database!

Comment: Create a table with I’d, permission name, description, and users and call it permissions. In the user’s table add a field and add all permissions ids separated by commas. In your code create a little function to find if a user have a permission or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing application permissions in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311413/storing-application-permissions-in-a-database)

Comment: Ah thank you. This does but your explaination is more clear for me. Thank you!